# Test NetBeans Web Application in Hudson

Tags: web-applications, netbeans, hudson

I'm trying to set up a Web Project created in the NetBeans IDE on Hudson for testing. It is configured to be deployed in a Tomcat server.

Everything is set up but I get a failure during execution of the job:

```
.../jobs/Xinco Web/workspace/trunk/XincoWebApp/nbproject/build-impl.xml:256: The Java EE server classpath is not correctly set up - server home directory is missing.
Either open the project in the IDE and assign the server or setup the server classpath manually.
For example like this:
    ant -Dj2ee.server.home=<app_server_installation_directory>
```

I saw an example of working around this but for GlassFish. See the Build and Test by Hudson section [here](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/tutorial-most-simple-test-application-for-embedded-glassfish-netbeans-hudson/).

Any ideas?

**Edit:** The referenced link allows compilation to happen without a server, just referencing a jar file. I would like to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Hudson, select your XincoWebApp job, and select "Configure".

In the Build section, where you have your Ant task to build your job, click on the `Advanced...` button to expand the Hudson options.  One of the new options should be labeled `Java Options`.  Inside that input box, put in the text `-Dj2ee.server.home=<app_server_installation_directory>` where you replace `<app_server_installation_directory>` with the actual directory where your app server lives on the Hudson server.

Comment: I got that from the failure message. In the link they work around providing location of a jar file. Isn't there something like that for Tomcat?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific on what kind of answer you're looking for.  If the answer above isn't it, then I fail to see what you're actually asking.

Comment: So according to the link you referenced, the author added `j2ee.platform.classpath` and `j2ee.platform.embeddableejb.classpath` to his `project.properties` file, and his Hudson job started working.  Your Hudson appears to be asking for a property of `j2ee.server.home`; have you attempted adding that to your `project.properties` file and recompiling from there?  If so, what was the result?

Comment: I was able to provide the app_server_installation_directory and is working now.